Compute number of hours the user spent per day
I have Clocking table in database. I wanted to count the users' time spent per day.
For example 2024-03-21, user 1 spend 6.8 hours, the next day he spends n number of hours and so on (['6.8', 'n', ... 'n'])



user
date
timein
timeout




1
2024-03-21
10:42 AM
12:00 PM


1
2024-03-21
01:10 PM
06:00 PM


1
2024-03-22
01:00 PM
05:47 PM


...
...
...
...



This is my models.py
class Clocking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING)
    timein = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    timeout = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=False)

I wanted to get the list of hours spent per day, which would be really useful for me in plotting charts.

Why is this a CharField?

The funny thing is I don't know.  I just used table mapping, cause this database table already exists. This was from previous person who made this.

Then make it right. Django has better types for dates and times than CharField. It will also be easier to calculate with them.

Please don't use a CharField to keep track. Imagine that a person enters now, then how will that work? It means you make the number of possible values a lot larger, and also increases disk space usage, altough that last one is probably not that much of an issue.
There are essentially two options: working with TimeFields:
from django.conf import settings


class Clocking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateField()
    timein = models.TimeField()
    timeout = models.TimeField(null=True)
or work with two DateTimeFields:
from django.conf import settings


class Clocking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.DO_NOTHING)
    timein = models.DateTimeField()
    timeout = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
The second has three advantages: (1) it will also easily register time correctly on dates where the daylight saving time changes. Although these typically change on a sunday around 2:00 AM so to minimize the amount of problematic bookkeeping, it is still possible that this might happen, for example if the person is working in a different timezone at that time; (2) it also allows to have multiple Clockings on the same date easily, without extra bookkeeping; and (3) finally it also means we can have a Clocking that runs over midnight. Indeed, imagine a person clocking in at 9:00 PM and clocking out at 01:00 AM the next day, then with the old model this will be problematic, it would require first checking if the end time is earlier than the begin time.
With this we can generate statistics for the date when the item started with:
# second model
from django.db.models import F, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

Clocking.objects.filter(timeout__isnull=False).values(
    date=TruncDate('timein')
).annotate(total=Sum(F('timeout') - F('timein'))).order_by('date')


Note: Specifying null=False [Django-doc] is not necessary: fields are by default not NULLable.



Note: It is normally better to make use of the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL [Django-doc] to refer to the user model, than to use the User model [Django-doc] directly. For more information you can see the referencing the User model section of the documentation.


I changed the fields to datetime, it's actually easy to compute time this way. Thank you for helping and for explaining the details. I'll keep this in mind.

Lastly, how can I combine the number of hours on same date?

@zhini: normally you do with the .values(..).annotate(...) trick in the last code fragment of the answer.

I got it. I shouldn't add the order_by at the last code fragment. It solved my problem. Thank you!

if you want to get the user spend time, you can select all of records in one date, then sum all the users (timein - timeout), for this you can convert the Charfield into a datetime object with the built-in library, or the best practice is to change your database field type into DateTimeField or TimeField.
